# openstack:rejoin-stack.sh script not working after reboot

Tags: openstack

I have installed devstack on ubuntu 14.04. i have run ./stack.sh and got the dash board.but once i reboot my system and try to run rejoin-stack.sh command.
the output is:
pradeep@pradeep-Inspiron-3521:~/devstack$ rejoin-stack.sh
rejoin-stack.sh: command not found

Comment: Try `./rejoin-stack.sh` (add the dot-slash prefix).

Answer (score 0):

devstack is not really meant to survive a reboot. You need to run stack.sh again. You will lose any existing information in the openstack services.